# Spring Boot REST API, using Hibernate+JPA, how to address concurrent data access overwriting transactions in multithreaded envrionment

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot Rest API that exposes CRUD operations on an Entity. I use a JPARepository. One of the API endpoints allows services to be added to a WorkProposal. When a service is added; it triggers a lookup to an external API. This lookup can take awhile; and so is run in a thread. Multiple services start multiple threads. After the lookup completes, the returned items are added to the WorkProposal, then .save() is called on the repository. Another API endpoint updates the status of the WorkProposal (a simple Boolean). This status can be updated while the lookups running in threads are still running. When the lookup threads complete, their save overwrites the status update and resets the status to it's previous state. I'm wondering how to avoid this issue. My expected result is that the status update made in `quoteWorkProposal` persists after the lookups complete.

I've included relevant code; but not entire classes

**WorkProposal**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="work_proposal")
@Getter
@Setter
public class WorkProposal implements Serializable {
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "work_proposal_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Set<ServiceRequested> servicesRequested = new HashSet<>();

    public boolean addServiceRequested(ServiceRequested serviceRequestedToAdd) {
        return servicesRequested.add(serviceRequestedToAdd);
    }

    @Column(name = "quoted")
    private Boolean quoted = new Boolean(false);

}
```

**ServiceRequested**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="work_proposal_service_requested")
@Setter
@Getter
public class ServiceRequested implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "loading")
    private Boolean loading = new Boolean(false);

}
```

**REST API Endpoints**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("work-proposal")
public class WorkProposalResource {

    @PostMapping("/{token}/service-requested")
    public WorkProposal addServiceRequested(@PathVariable String token, @RequestBody ServiceRequested serviceRequested) throws WorkProposalNotFoundException {
        return workProposalService.addServiceRequested(token, serviceRequested);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{token}/quote")
    public WorkProposal quoteWorkProposal(@PathVariable String token) throws WorkProposalNotFoundException {
        return workProposalService.quoteWorkProposal(token);
    }

}
```

**WorkProposalService**

```
@EnableAsync
@Transactional
public class WorkProposalService {

    public WorkProposal addServiceRequested(String token, ServiceRequested serviceRequested) throws WorkProposalNotFoundException {
        WorkProposal workProposal = lookupWorkProposal(token);
        workProposal.addServiceRequested(serviceRequested);
        //Begin a lookup
        addLookup(workProposal, serviceRequested);
        return workProposalRespository.save(workProposal);
    }

    public WorkProposal quoteWorkProposal(String token) throws WorkProposalNotFoundException {
        WorkProposal workProposal = lookupWorkProposal(token);
        workProposal.setQuoted(true);
        return workProposalRespository.save(workProposal);
    }

    protected void addLookup(WorkProposal workProposal, ServiceRequested serviceRequested) {
            serviceRequested.setLoading(true);
            /* THREAD START */ //Async
            completionService.submit(() -> {
                Set<ExternalItem> externalItems = externalAPIService.getItems(workProposal);
                workProposal.addAllExternalItems(externalItems);
                serviceRequested.setLoading(false);
                workProposalRespository.save(workProposal);
                return null;
            });
        }
    }

    private WorkProposal lookupWorkProposal(String token) throws WorkProposalNotFoundException {
        return Optional.ofNullable(workProposalRespository.getWorkProposalByToken(UUID.fromString(token)))
                .orElseThrow(WorkProposalNotFoundException::new);
    }
}
```

**WorkProposalRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface WorkProposalRespository extends JpaRepository<WorkProposal, Long> {

    WorkProposal getWorkProposalByToken(UUID token);

}
```